# How to redirect to custom web page after seeing if a string is present in web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, dynamic

How to redirect to a link after checking if a set of string is present in web page

For example:
Hello world is present in web page
script checks if "hello world" is present and if so then redirect to a link

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through each element on the page and test for the search string.

**NOTE** put this in the `<head>` section of your page, not in `<body>`

```js
document.body.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(e => {
  if (e.innerText.includes("hello world")) window.location = "http://google.com";
})
```

You could loop through each element on the page and see if the search string exists...

```
document.body.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(e => {
   if (e.innerText.includes("hello world")) window.location = "http://google.com";
})
```